# Pull docker images from private registry on remote host?

Tags: curl, docker, https, dockerpy

I've docker image pushed onto private registry running on host1. However, when I try to fetch the image from remote host (host2), I do see the following error:

Docker command: `docker pull <host1>:5000/alpine:latest`
Result : `Error response from daemon: Get https://<host1>:5000/v1/_ping: EOF`

How can i make `docker pull` fetch the image with `http` call instead of `https` ??

I've explored all the options including starting docker daemon with `--insecure-registry` flag. None of them seem to have any affect on what I'm trying to achieve here.

```
Docker version 1.11.1
OS Type : Linux
```

The following curl command from remote host fetched data

```
curl -1 http://<host1>:5000/v1/_ping
```

Same curl command with https: seems to have problem fetching data

```
 curl -1 https://<host1>:5000/v1/_ping

 curl: (35) Encountered end of file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a non-secure registry but you need to update your deamon

https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/

1. Open the /etc/default/docker file or /etc/sysconfig/docker for editing.
   Depending on your operating system, your Engine daemon start options.
2. Edit (or add) the DOCKER_OPTS line and add the `--insecure-registry` flag. This flag takes the URL of your registry, for example.
   `DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry myregistrydomain.com:5000"`
3. Close and save the configuration file.
4. Restart your Docker daemon

The command you use to restart the daemon depends on your operating system. For example, on Ubuntu, this is usually the service docker stop and service docker start command.

Comment: That doesn't resolve the problem though. I made the following changes            1. Open daemon file under /etc/sysconfig/ and added  DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry <host1>:5000". Restarted docker daemon after these changes.  Here's the error Error response from daemon: Get https://<host1>:5000/v1/_ping: EOF